# Django: How to retrieve the logged in user's details

Tags: python, django

I am in the process of learning Django. I am trying to create a simple directory web app. I am able to print out all the users details for the main directory page. However, I want to add a feature that when a person logs into the directory app they are brought to their 'profile' page where they will be able to see all their own details e.g. business name, profile pic.

I know how to retrieve the default fields e.g. username and email. But cannot seem to retrieve the custom fields that I declared myself. Here is my attempts so far...

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

#additional classes
business_name = models.CharField(max_length=191,blank=True)
trade = models.CharField(max_length=191,blank=True)
portfolio_site = models.URLField(blank=True)
profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Views.py:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
  profile = UserProfileInfo.objects.filter(user=request.user)
  context = { 'profile': profile }
  return render(request, 'dir_app/profile.html',context)
```

Profile.html:

```
 <div class="container-fluid text-center">
    {% for p in profile %}
       <h3>{{p.business_name}}</h3>
    {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

Comment: Looks like you did not create a `UserProfileInfo` for the given `request.user`.

Comment: are you sure there is a profile, what if you print `print(profile.count())`?

Comment: On the home page I show all of the business names that have registered (2). I use a simple for loop which seems to do the trick. But I don't know how to just return the information of the logged in user.

Comment: you obtain the profile with `request.user.userprofileinfo`.

Answer (score 0):

Since UserProfileInfo is related to User via OneToOneField, you can have one UserProfileInfo per User. So, instead of Filter, you can simply get your desired UserProfileInfo object through your current (logged in) User as follows.
views.py,

```
profile = UserProfileInfo.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

Also, before you can get a request.user object, you have to make sure that your user is authenticated and logged in. Otherwise, you might get None in place of a User object and therefore, no associated UserProfileInfo.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a `OneToOneField` there is only one `Profile` object for a `User`, you thus can obtain this with:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    profile = request.user.userprofileinfo
    return render(request, 'my_template.html',{'profile': profile})
```

Then in the template, you render it with:

```
{{ profile.business_name }}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use it directly on template without sending it f:

```
{{request.user.userprofile}}
```